# Pipe Unity CLI compilation log file while command is running in Windows Batch

Tags: unity-game-engine, logging, jenkins, compilation, command-line-interface

I´m compiling a Unity project via CLI and it takes a while. I would like to see the compilation output straight in the console, not in the log file. In [this page](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html) I´ve found a few arguments but none helped me:

**-batchmode:** only prevents dialogs (basically)

**-stackTraceLogType:** only improve the details of the log

**-logFile :** only allows me to set a path not to console e.g. `-logFile toConsole`

I´m doing it via Jenkins so that´s why I need a detailed console straight on screen.

*Ps.: Unity has a Jenkins plugin who does it properly piping the log file, but I can't use due project needs.*

Comment: A poor workaround is `-log build.log` and then `type build.log`.

Answer (score 2):

If you specify the -logFile parameter without the path of a log file, Unity should output to the console, as mentioned here: https://effectiveunity.com/articles/how-to-create-your-own-unity-cloud-build-part-3/. But unfortunately I've only managed this to work on MacOS, for me it doesn't work on Windows.